# Pending postbacks with TextChanged event and saving

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, postback

I have a textbox called 'Value' (among other textboxes) on an ASP page. I have an event handler hooked up to the textbox so that when the textbox contents are changed, the event handler runs (control.textchanged event)

I have another command button ('Save') which saves the textbox value to the database and then calls window.close() via javascript. The problem is that when the textbox is changed and the user clicks on the 'Save' button without clicking off the textbox, the value is somehow saved in the database but the javascript does not run. Then, the user will think the value did not save because the window did not automatically close, and when they click 'save' again, the value in the textbox saves for a second time and then the javascript runs which closes the window.

It is very similar to this issue (http://forums.asp.net/t/523981.aspx?Pending+Postback+Troubles) but i do not understand the solution provided there.

Can anyone provide a method which may prevent the record being created twice in this instance?

Thanks,
c

Comment: Then remove the `AutoPostBack` from the `TextBox` and let the user always click the save button. The code can remain in the `TextChanged` even if you want, it will be triggered also on save-button-click. But i would move it to the save-button click-event handler.

Comment: Can you show us your HTML and code behind?